# Git merge master into branch and new feature

Tags: git, github, svn, version-control

I have 2 components being developed at the same time component A and component B. And component A needs to use component B for it to be complete.

If component B is completed first and then merged into master as it is a stand alone component. How should I go about getting that into A so it can be completed?

After merging B into master should I merge master into A?

Should I merge A in half done and then retrench? (This doesn't seem correct)

Is there some option that I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest this _After merging B into master should I merge master into A?_

Comment: After merging B into master, merge master into A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge B into master and then merge master into A.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a matter of etiquette on your repository, there's no right answer except the answer given by the owners of your code repository.

However the thing which is (almost) universal is to avoid merging A and B together directly.  If A and B are truly separate pieces of work, they should be merged into master individually.

The most common work flow here would be:

- The developer of B completes the work, then submits a [pull request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests)
- The pull request is approved and **B is merged into master**
- A's developer **merges master into A**. No pull request required, A's developer owns A's branch and can change it as much as they like.
- A's developer completes the work, then submits a pull request
- The pull request is approved and **A is merged into master**.